# R - Error with mtext( ) that doesn't interrupt boxplot printing

Tags: r, error-handling, boxplot

As it is well known that one can produce rudimentary graphics with `boxplot()` and add text in them with `mtext()`. For an example:

```
boxplot(iris)
mtext("something")
mtext("...testing",line=1)
```

As I was trying to merge these three lines in to one I came up with a rather weird idea which I think is not even supported by R (at least to my basic knowledge):

```
boxplot(iris)&mtext("something")+mtext("...testing",line=1)
```

Which looks odd to begin with and produces the following error:

```
Error in mtext("...testing", line = 1) & mtext("something") + mtext("...testing",  : 
operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

But even with the error and the allegedly "wrong" scripting the actual boxplot prints similarly as it would with correct coding.

Can anyone explain to me why R  behaves like this? Why is the boxplot being printed correctly despite of the given error and (to my knowledge) improper coding?

Comment: It probably just escapes `&` and `+`, as arguments are not numeric, logical or complex types.

Comment: It seems so. It's interesting to note that the operators `&` and `+` has to be in that precise order. If I put `+mtext(...)` before `&mtext(...)`, the latter `mtext(...)` is omitted from output. Also, I can't use the same operator twice.